# Не могу понять ошибки,которою выдает valgrind (invalid read of size 8)

Tags: c, указатели, segmentation-fault, valgrind

```
req_t*   parse_request(input_t *all)
{
  req_t *temp;
  temp = (req_t*) malloc (sizeof(req_t));
  temp = NULL;
  char map_size_n[10] = "\0";
  char map_size_m[10] = "\0";
  int i  =  2;
  int j;
  int count;
  temp->elem->sign = all->array[0];

  while ( all->array[i] != ' ' )
  {
    map_size_n[i-2] = all->array[i];
    i++;
  }
  count = i + 1;
  while ( all->array[i] != '\n' )
  {
    map_size_m[i - count] = all->array[i];
    i++;
  }
    temp->map->h = atoi(map_size_n);
    temp->map->w = atoi(map_size_m);

  temp->map->map = malloc(temp->map->h * sizeof(char*));
  for (j = 0; j < temp->map->h; j++)
   temp->map->map[j] = malloc(temp->map->w * sizeof(char));
  count = i + 1;
 for (i = 0; i < temp->map->h; i++)
  {
   for (j = 0; j < temp->map->w; j++)
      temp->map->map[i][j] = all->array[count+ j + i * 10];
    count++;
  }

  j = 0;
  char elem_size_n[10] = "\0";
  char elem_size_m[10] = "\0";

  while (!isdigit(all->array[count]))
    count++;

 while ( all->array[count] != ' ')
  {
    elem_size_n[j] = all->array[count];
    count++;
    j++;
  }

  i = 0;
  while ( all->array [count] != '\n')
  {
    elem_size_m[i] = all->array[count];
    count++;
    i++;
  }
  count++;

  temp->elem->melem_h = atoi(elem_size_n);
  temp->elem->melem_w = atoi(elem_size_m);

  temp->elem->elem = malloc(temp->elem->melem_h * sizeof(char*));
  for (i = 0; i < temp->elem->melem_h; i++)
    temp->elem->elem[i] = malloc(temp->elem->melem_w * sizeof(char));

  for ( i = 0; i < temp->elem->melem_h; i++)
  {
    for ( j = 0; j < temp->elem->melem_w; j++ )
      temp->elem->elem[i][j] = all->array[count + j + temp->elem->melem_h * i];
    count++;
  }


  return temp;
}
```

//header

```
#ifndef _FILLER_H_
#define _FILLER_H_

typedef struct map_s
{
  int h;
  int w;
  char **map;
}              map_t;

typedef struct input_s
{
  char *array;
}              input_t;


typedef struct elem_s
{
  char sign;
  int melem_h;
  int melem_w;
  char **elem;
}              elem_t;

typedef struct res_s
{
  int x_coord;
  int y_coord;
}              res_t;

typedef struct connect_s
{
  int elem_h;
  int elem_w;
  int i_lB;
  int j_lB;
  int i_lT;
  int j_lT;
  int i_bR;
  int j_bR;
  int i_bL;
  int j_bL;

}              connect_t;

typedef struct req_s
{
  map_t *map;
  elem_t *elem;
}              req_t;

input_t* input();
req_t* parse_request(input_t *all);
connect_t* find_connect_position(req_t *temp);
res_t* scan_algorithm (req_t *temp, connect_t *pos);
void print_res (res_t *res);



#endif // _FILLER_H_
```

Сообщения:

```
==8350== Invalid read of size 8
==8350== at 0x400769: parse_request (in /home/mafara/work/cep/courses/cunix/ex11/filler)
==8350== by 0x400ECB: main (in /home/mafara/work/cep/courses/cunix/ex11/filler)
==8350== Address 0x8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==8350==
==8350==
==8350== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
==8350== Access not within mapped region at address 0x8
==8350== at 0x400769: parse_request (in /home/mafara/work/cep/courses/cunix/ex11/filler)
==8350== by 0x400ECB: main (in /home/mafara/work/cep/courses/cunix/ex11/filler)
```

Answer (score 1):

Когда код написан таким образом, что трудно понять, что он делает, то это всегда является неизбежной причиной наличия в нем различного рода ошибок. На мой взгляд этот код следует целиком переписать.

Сразу же бросается в глаза утечка памяти в предложениях

```
temp = (req_t*) malloc (sizeof(req_t));
temp = NULL;
```

так как сначала указателю `temp` присваивается адрес выделенной динамически памяти, а затем этому указателю присваивается значение NULL, что ведет к потере адреса выделенной памяти, которая уже не может быть освобождена.

Или другой фрагмент кода

```
count = i + 1;
while ( all->array[i] != '\n' )
{
    map_size_m[i - count] = all->array[i];
    i++;
}
```

В этом фрагменте для массива `map_size_m` используется индекс равный `-1`, так как выражение для индекса `i - count` эквивалентно выражению `i - ( i + 1 )` по определению значения переменной `count`, что соответствует `-1`.

Возможно код содержит и другие ошибки, но так как совершенно не понятно, что он делает, то его трудно анализировать.

Answer (score 0):

А вот этот кусок

```
temp = (req_t*) malloc (sizeof(req_t));
temp = NULL;
```

Вас не смущает? Выделили память, потом потерли указатель (память теперь осталась висеть и уже потеряна). А потом (ниже по коду) пишем по нулевому указателю. Это и приводит к указанным ругательстам. А так как код обращается в пределах первого мегабайта, это приводит к падению.

Comment: Хорошо,спасибо)Убрала temp == NULL,но все равно выбивает Segmentation fault ,добавляется conditional move or jump depends on uninitialized values @KoVadim

Comment: как минимум это может быть здесь `temp->elem->sign = all->array[0];` - память под elem не выделялась.